# VBS WScript.Run fails after passing Exists test

Tags: vbscript

In a couple of place in my code I check if the file exists (it does) then I try to Run the file as above, or get the `DateLastModified`, and get errors about file not found or invalid path.  How can the script NOT see a file after confirming it exists?

I'm  working up a .vbs script that tries to run an Access .mdb file.  The `WScript.Run` command seems to choke on the filename, but putting a `MsgBox()` before that call to display the path allows Run to work properly.  I don't want to display a popup.

Error is:

> The directory name is invalid.

How is this possible and how can I get around it?

Here is code:

```
AccessFileName  = "App.mdb"         
LocalPath       = "C:\Folder\"  

SET ws = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    
path = Chr(34) & LocalPath & AccessFileName  & Chr(34) 

if (fso.FileExists(LocalPath & AccessFileName)) THEN    
   'MsgBox(path)   'Uncommenting this line removes the error    
    ws.Run path   'This line errors   
End If
```

Comment: Have you tried running it through the msaccess executable rather than directly activating the mdb file? http://www.devhut.net/2010/09/14/launch-open-an-ms-access-database-using-a-vbscript/

Comment: @Rich -I haven't, not wild about the method (hard coding exe paths for one).  The way I have it, (except for calling the variable AccessFileName), I can actually pass any kind of file.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error(though in Japanese)
Happening after Call fso.MoveFolder(parentFolder & childFolder,destination & "\")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to open your file with shell `.InvokeVerb` method:

```vbs
AccessFileName = "App.mdb"
LocalPath = "C:\Folder\"

If CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").FileExists(LocalPath & AccessFileName) Then
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(LocalPath).ParseName(AccessFileName).InvokeVerb
End If
```

**UPD:** Both ActiveX [`WScript.Shell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahcz2kh6(v=vs.84).aspx) and [`Shell.Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537707(v=vs.85).aspx) uses native windows shell to perform a file execution.
The first one launches new process via WSH core located in wscript.exe, cscript.exe, wshom.ocx, jscript.dll, vbscript.dll, ets, `.Run` and `.Exec` methods of `WsShell` object provides wide control on the launched process, and second one located in Shell32.dll, uses `.InvokeVerb` method of `IShellDispatch` object, called without name, runs default verb equals to the windows explorer "open" command.
In case of any issues connected to WSH, explorer might still works without any proplems. If it does, that is just a work-around, I can't say what's wrong definetely without close look.

Comment: Can you point me to any reference on InvokeVerb or explain why this might help?

Comment: @MAW74656 I've updated my answer with brief description.

Comment: Note sure this solves my problem, but its the most thoughtful and potentially useful answer here, so bounty awarded.  I will be doing further testing to figure out if this is also the green check answer.

Comment: I've changed my script to use this and haven't had a single failure.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can give this a shot. You probably do not need the quotes around the path, but I included it as a comment if you want to give it a shot. You just put quotes twice if you need to include a quote character in a string:

```vbs
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

AccessFileName  = "App.mdb"    
LocalPath       = "C:\Folder\"  

Set ws = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    
' path = """" & LocalPath & AccessFileName  & """" <-- probably unnecessary
path = LocalPath & AccessFileName

If (fso.FileExists(path)) Then
    Set file = fso.GetFile(path)   
    'MsgBox(path)   'Uncommenting this line removes the error    
    ws.Run file.Path   'This line errors   
End If
```

Comment: Also, wouldn't your commented out line simple add an empty string to both sides?

Answer (score 1):

Hello the following code worked for me.

Basically this code gets a folder object and loops through all files in a folder and checks if its the one that you named.  This it runs the application.

```vbs
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

AccessFileName = "App.mdb"
LocalPath = "C:\Folder\"

Set myFolder = fso.GetFolder(LocalPath)

For each myFile in myFolder.Files

    If myFile.Name = AccessFileName Then
        'Wscript.Echo myFile.Name
        ws.Run myFolder.Path & "\" & myFile.Name
    End If

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not make any sense. Having a MsgBox line is altering the behavior of the program!!!

I feel it is probably some weird invisible character somewhere which is getting activated when you comment the line.

Try retyping the If block without the MsgBox in between.

Comment: I don't really understand your answer... are you saying that you see the same behavior and agree its weird?  ALso, I've tried the code with the MsgBox, without the MsgBox, with it commented out, so no joy there.

Comment: Sorry I did not clarify that. No, I do not see the behavior in my test programs. I also feel your code has no problem at all and it is not possible that a MsgBox command alters the way the program behaves. So I suggested you to retype the If block without the Msgbox line and see what happens. If you already did it and still have a problem you can try res = ws.Run(path) instead of just ws.Run path. If that too causes trouble then I am also stumped.

Comment: Also I dont think this is the complete code as I dont see the declaration for 'fso'. Can you post more complete code and exact error?

Comment: Exact error is in question, and the fso declaration is nothing worth mentioning: `SET fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`

Comment: Hey, i just wanted to see the whole program in context not a declaration. Anyway, i still feel Msgbox should not alter program behavior.